# Trying to only look through part of a 2D array to optimize my code but isn't working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to optimize a part of my code where I look through all nodes in a grid, these nodes are stored in a 2D array and their location in the array matches their position in the world.

What I am doing in the part I am trying to optimize is look through nodes in the grid and with A* pathfinding finding the distance between nodes. I don't have to look through all nodes in the grid however as I have a set range.

What I had before was this:

```
foreach(Node n in grid.grid)
```

A simple foreach loop on the grid. This works fine on grids with a size of around 25x25 but I want to be able to have way larger grids than that.

Here is the solution I came up to optimize it:

```
Node startNode = grid.grid[unit.gridX - (maxRange + unit.movementRange), unit.gridY - (maxRange + unit.movementRange)];

        for(int x = 0; x < (unit.movementRange + maxRange) * 2 + 1; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < (unit.movementRange + maxRange) * 2 + 1; y++)
            {
                Node currentNode = grid.grid[startNode.gridX + x, startNode.gridY + y];
```

With this, it only looks in a square around it instead of all nodes in the grid.
This works the way I want it to but it doesn't help optimization.
This should, in theory, make the size of the grid irrelevant but it doesn't. If I increase the size of the grid both increase in the time it takes, if anything the solution I came up with is slightly slower.

I am using Unity 2019.3.0f3.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should be aware 2019.3f6 is the current and live version of 2019.3 you are on a beta version - but for this it shouldnt matter although I recall f3 was a bit of a flake.    What specifically are you struggling with, looping through an array like you are there should take next to no time.

Comment: @BugFinder Well the loop itself isn't the problem, the problem is the content. Right now each loop draws a path between two nodes to find the distance between them and if a unit that is standing on the node from which the path originates can reach it with the ranges the unit has. I want to loop through as few nodes as possible.

Comment: What are you doing with every currentNode? And how are you measuring script working time?

Comment: @Hermesis currentNode is the node I draw a path to that iteration of the loop and measurement of script working time is simply a Stopwatch from System.Diagnostics.

Comment: so for `maxRange = 1` and `unit.movementRange = 1` there will be 25 `currentNode`'s. You are measuring the distance between each of them and some originated point? I don't get the process. There are more simple ways to find distance or shortest path. Your stopwatch logging time every update, every `for(x` loop, every `for(y` loop?

Comment: @Hermesis I know that there are simpler ways to calculate this but I need to use pathfinding as the grid isn't empty, the obstacles on the grid aren't static either. The stopwatch simply begins at the start of the function and stops at the end, it never touches the for loops, it also isn't really relevant to what I am doing as I know that it does it job and accuratly measures the time it takes to execute this code.

Comment: All this code looks fine, I think the problem is in either grid implementation or in pathfinding. Try logging stopwatch in every loop before and after pathfinding